# why there is no non cyclic group other than $D_{61}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I know that there are two non isomorphic groups of order $122$. One is cyclic group of order $122 $ and another is $D_{61}$. I know that all cyclic groups are isomorphic. But I can not understand why there is no non cyclic group other than $D_{61}$.

Can anyone please make me understand?

Comment: Look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291349/looking-for-a-simple-proof-that-groups-of-order-2p-are-up-to-isomorphism-mat