# Non-abelian group with 362 elements is isomorphic to the dihedral group 181 ($D_{181})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So i am trying to prove that a non-abelian group with 362 elements is isomorphic to the dihedral group 181 (D181)?
So the dihedral group has 362 elements(181*2). Exactly the same as the non-abelian group. And the elements of D181 are all matrices. Dn is non-abelian for every n (except 1,2). How can i map the elements from the non-abelian group to the dihedral group?  I can't figure it out.
Any tips?

Comment: N.B.:  $181$ is prime, so see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291349/looking-for-a-simple-proof-that-groups-of-order-2p-are-up-to-isomorphism-mat)

Comment: yes, and how does that help me?

Comment: It helps you by answering your question. The point is that it is easier and more useful to solve this problem for groups of order $2p$ for $p$ prime, rather than just to do it in the special case when $p=181$.

Comment: For an explicit isomorphism, you can map any element of order $181$ in one group to any element of order $181$ in the other, and any element of order $2$ in one group to any element of order $2$ in the other. (It is not always as easy as that to find an isomorphism between two groups.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $362=2\times181$ and $181$ is prime.

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291349/looking-for-a-simple-proof-that-groups-of-order-2p-are-up-to-isomorphism-mat), groups of order $2p$ with $p$ prime are either cyclic or dihedral,

so if it's non-Abelian, it must be dihedral.