# Action of a group on a set with $7$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group $\lvert\,G\,\rvert = 14$ acting on a set $M$ of $7$ elements without fixed points. Prove that the action is transitive and that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$. I proved that the action is transitive but I can't prove the second part, I don't know even how to start! Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part has been proved at this site using various methods. In fact, any group of order $2p$, for $p>2$ prime is isomorphic to either $C_{2p}$ or $D_p$. For $p=7$ we obtain your  result.

References:

[Looking for a simple proof that groups of order $2p$ are up to isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$ and $D_{p}$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291349/looking-for-a-simple-proof-that-groups-of-order-2p-are-up-to-isomorphism-mat)