# How is $\Bbb{Z}_2\otimes \Bbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_6$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I am currently reading the book  *Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists* by Anthony Zee and he wrote something about isomorphism I could not quite understand.

> Now we come in for a bit of a surprise. Consider $\Bbb{Z}_2 \otimes \Bbb{Z}_3$ consisting of $(n, m)$, which we compose by $(n + n' \mod 2, m + m' \mod3)$. Again, we start with $(0, 0)$ and add $(1, 1)$ repeatedly:
>
> $(0,0)\{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow (1,1) \{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow(0,2)\{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow(1,0)\{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow(0,1)\{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow(1,2)\{+(1,1)\}\rightarrow (0,0)$
>
> We are back where we started! In the process, we cycled through all
> six elements of $\Bbb{Z}_2 \otimes \Bbb{Z}_3$. We conclude that the
> six elements $\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)$ } describe
> $\Bbb{Z}_6$

Further he writes-

> Thus, $\Bbb Z_2 \otimes \Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_6$ are isomorphic; they are literally the same group. Note that this
> phenomenon, of a possible isomorphism between $\Bbb Z_p \otimes \Bbb Z_q$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{pq}$, does not require p
> and q to be prime, only relatively prime. (Consider the example of $\Bbb Z_4 \otimes \Bbb Z_9$.)

And hence my question: How did the author establish the one-to-one mapping between the groups claimed to be isomorphic? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: He showed that the former is a finite cyclic group of order $6$, hence it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_6$.

Comment: I don't think $\otimes$ is the notation you're looking for. Either $\times$ or $\oplus$ would be more common.

Comment: Zee used this as the notation for Direct Product. I am new to this stuff so don't really know.

Comment: That's fine then. A little non-standard as that symbol usually denotes a different product, but fine.

Comment: What Arthur said! For your information. the symbol $\otimes$ more commonly means the *tensor product* of (in this case) abelian groups. When the claim in the title becomes *false* as the tensor product of these two groups is the trivial group $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write his mapping by literally taking the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ mod 2 and 3 respectively:

| $a \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ | $a \mod 2$ | $a \mod 3$ | $(n, m) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $(0, 0)$ |
| $1$ | $1$ | $1$ | $(1, 1)$ |
| $2$ | $0$ | $2$ | $(0, 2)$ |
| $3$ | $1$ | $0$ | $(1, 0)$ |
| $4$ | $0$ | $1$ | $(0, 1)$ |
| $5$ | $1$ | $2$ | $(1, 2)$ |

Note that since $\mathbb{Z}_6$ under addition is the cyclic group of order 6, you can form its elements by repeated addition of $1$, and likewise in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ the element $(1, 1)$ is a generator that behaves identically.

Answer (score 1):

[**Lemma:** If a group $G$ has order $2p$ for prime $p>2$, then $G$ is isomorphic to either $\Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291349/10404)

Since $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3$ is abelian and $D_3$ is not, we must have that $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Here $D_p$ is the dihedral group of order $2p$.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the text, you will see that the correspondence $[1]\in \mathbb{Z}_6 \mapsto ([1],[1]) \in \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ is one possible isomorphism.

Comment: Is this from Zee?

Comment: @Sarthak I did not understand the question. "Zee"?
Hint: just note that the text shows that the element $(1,1)$ has order $6$.

Comment: I mean has Anthony Zee written this in his book? My point is that $Z_6$ being the group of $6$th roots of unity will have the elements $\{\exp(2\pi j/6) \}$ where $j$ goes from 0 to 5. How can we establish a mapping between these and the ordered pairs we found above?

Comment: The structure of this group of units is exactly that: there are 6 exactly elements and at least one of them has order 6. But it is important to note that usually one writes $\mathbb{Z}_6$ meaning the group of integers modulo $6$ under addition - which has the exact same structure  as the group of  $6$th roots of unity under multiplication.

Comment: @Sarthak If you prefer, you can map $exp(2\pi/6) \mapsto (1,1)$

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was helpful! I have accepted the answer by ConMan as correct since it explicitly shows the mapping.